# How to extract a compressed directory to a specific filename?

Tags: bash, tar

I have a compressed file `file.tar.bz2` and I want to extract it, the problem is the file which is compressed is a single directory with an unknown name. As I want to use this in a script, I want to specify the name of the resulting directory so it is no longer unknown.

How can I specify the name of the extracted directory?

I tried redirecting to `stdout`:

```
tar -xf file.tar.bz2 -O > file
```

but that didn't work because the result was an executable:

```
file file
file: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=fe7990e83d40c3e28bd1cacd345468bfa9be3d85, stripped
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I restate your problem:

- You have a compressed *archive* which contains a directory.
- You don't know the name of that directory.
- You want to find out that directory's name.

May I suggest the `tar -tf file.tar.bz2 > file`. The `-t` parameter stands for *tell*. This will tell you the contents of the archive. The `file` file will contain the table of contents of that compressed tarball.

From there, you could parse the `file` file to find the name of the directory. In fact, I just tested this:

```
directory_name=$(tar tf test.tar.bz | sed 's#/.*##'  | sort -u)
```

If the tarball contains only a single directory, the shell variable `$directory_name` will be set to that directory name. If there are multiple directories, then `$directory_name` will contain them in a NL separated list.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without reading the entire archive?

Comment: If this folder is the only folder in the archive, you can use the `head -1`` command to just pull off the first line of the `tar tf` command: `directory_name=$(tar tf test.tar.bz | head -1 | sed 's#/.*##'  | sort -u)`